# Can't submit arguments in the URL when using a HTTP GET to fetch data from the db

Tags: javascript, jsp, http, get

First of all the initial problem was that in the application there is a return button which uses < javascript:history.back() > to return to the previous page. What works just fine in its self.

BUT when clicked throws you to a page that asks you if you want to resubmit your form. This is happening because the previous page uses POST to get some data from the DB and as a safety measure ask you if it would be wise to resubmit the form.

Now everything is clear and understandable here, so i changed the method to GET.
Thinking that would solve everything, but sadly that is not the case.

This is the form in question.

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8"
        action="../../../S/S/S/<%=CinematiqueProduit.SER_SYNTH_PROD%>"
        method="GET" id="formule">
        <table align="center" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><i18n:message>Société</i18n:message> &nbsp;</td>
                <td><b><%=ParamLibFacade.getLabelText(ApplicationProperties.getCompany(), Table.COMPANY)%></b></td>
                <td><i18n:message>Code produit</i18n:message> &nbsp;</td>
                <td><select name="cProd" onChange="validation('cProd')">
                        <option value="titre"><i18n:message>Sélectionner un produit</i18n:message></option>
                        <%
                            i = 0;
                        %>
                        <%
                            while (i < listeProSoc.nbProduit) {
                        %>
                        <%
                            produit = listeProSoc.codeProduit[i];
                        %>
                        <%
                            if (produit.equals(produitorigine)) {
                        %>
                        <option selected="selected" value="<%=produit%>"><%=listeProSoc.libProduit[i]%></option>
                        <%
                            } else {
                        %>
                        <option value="<%=produit%>">
                            <%=listeProSoc.libProduit[i]%></option>
                        <%
                            }
                                i++;
                        %>
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p align="center"></p>
        <input id="modifier" type="hidden" value="1"></input>

    </form>
```

It has its action already set. Which is fine. The problem is that when the < onChange > is called in the < select > .

The function looks like as follows:

```
function validation(item) {
  var modifier = document.getElementById("modifier");
  modifier.setAttribute("value","1");
  var theForm = document.getElementById("formule");
  theForm.setAttribute("action","../../../S/S/S/<%=CinematiqueProduit.SER_SYNTH_PROD%>?Orig=<%=CinematiqueProduit.ORIG_LISTE%>");
  theForm.submit();
}
```

It does not change the action to what is set in this function. It has the needed information for the controller that is needed in the next page, without it the redirect is not done.

And i'm not sure why that might be happening.

Thank you in advance!!!!! And sorry if i'm missing something obvious! I'm just not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: I forgot to add that it takes the elements values in the form which have their name set. Like cProd. It passed that in the URL and not what i set in the function.

Comment: First, you should clean your code ... you can write more than one line of Java in a scriptlet .. but of course, you should not use scriplet at all... Your validation function that you have print, come from the jsp I guess .. what is the function on the client side ? once compiled by the server.

Comment: This is the project im working on at work. None of this code is mine. This whole page is like this. Who ever made it put the JavaScript and everything in this single page. :/

Comment: Ok, hope it was an intern or a old app ;) From what I can see, the only think done is to update the `input modifier` to 1 (already was) then set the action with a static String for the action. Then submit the form. To see what is throw, you can use a web developer tool to see the network usage. The submit should append the url with the input... Could you check the URL of the request send on submit ?

Comment: It appends the value of cProd at the end of it. Which is the problem at hand. It just does not care for the action set in the function :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you update the action, I would do this simply like this :

```
theForm.action = "../../../S/S/S/<%=CinematiqueProduit.SER_SYNTH_PROD%>"
```

(but is it necessary ? what other function could submit the form ? If none, just put the action directly in the form)

Then, for the `orig` attribute, simply add a hidden input, like the `modifier` one

```
<input id="modifier" name="modifier" type="hidden" value="1"></input>
<input id="orig" name="orig" type="hidden" value="<%=CinematiqueProduit.ORIG_LISTE%>" />
```

I have add the name for the modifier input if needed but it was probably not used before...

Using this solution should generate the correct URL for a GET request using the submit function on the form.

## EDIT

If you need to set the action URL dynamicly, update the values of the inputs instead of putting value in the URL.

Using a GET method recreate the attribute, overriding those you would have put at the begin.

This is why you need to use hidden input to store some values. Just updates does to pass some values in the URL. The form will do the rest ;)

```
document.getElementById("orig").value = "<%=CinematiqueProduit.ORIG_LISTE%>";
var theForm = document.getElementById("formule");
theForm.action = "../../../S/S/S/<%=CinematiqueProduit.SER_SYNTH_PROD%>";
theForm.submit();
```

Comment: Iv already tried that and that works. The reason why im trying to make it work in this fashion is because there is another function in that code that calls another URL that goes to the next page.

Comment: @LeonCsergity Well, since a GET request change the URL, I guess this does not append the attribute but recreate it without using those already present in the action URL. So you should use this solution to let the form create is URL correctly on submit. Of course, you are free to update the orig input value in the functions (instead of the URL orig value). (I was about to add this in an edit)

Comment: @LeonCsergity it is not a guess, I test this, the attribute are override during the submit with the form values. So use `<input type="hidden" ... />` to store some dynamic values.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense!!! Just that i was so focused on doing it by the book that it did not even come to mind to just use it the way its functioning right now. Thank you! I shall try that now.

Comment: @LeonCsergity, the solution is doing it by the book actually ;) This is much more simple to use some hidden inputs, even for POST form because the form itself will manage the form container to use for the request. I never mix POST form with URL attributes either first because Servlet don't really support that and because I found that messy.

Comment: @LeonCsergity, is it ok for you ? Don't forgetto accept this answer if this suit you.

Comment: A sry. I totally forgot. Yes its perfect thank you again a lot!! :D